# Text not displaying correctly in react-admin interface

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

#### Edit: Solved

------

Some texts are not redering properly in "react admin" web interface.
Version: 2.8.5.

Default icons like "Edit" or "Clone" or even the links to my resources are rendered wrong.

If I explicity set a "label" in my fields, the text is rendered properly.

I've see some reference about this on a github issue (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2809), but I'm not working with translations or anything like that...

I really don't know what's wrong and how I can fix this... On a previous version the app was working...

Can someone help me?

Image example below (sorry, I've had to ommit some informations):
[image]

My App.js:

```
// in src/App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import { AcladvList, AcladvEdit, AcladvCreate } from './posts';
import { vmWareList, vmWareShow, vmWareEdit, vmWareCreate } from './vmWare';
import ACLIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Security';
import VMIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Computer';
import Dashboard from './dashboard';
import authProvider from './authProvider';

import customDataProvider from './customDataProvider';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { OidcSettings } from './oidcSettings';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    const tokenSessionItem = "oidc.user:" + OidcSettings.authority + ":" + OidcSettings.client_id;
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenSessionItem);
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `${token}`);
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://<ommited>/<ommited>',httpClient);
const dataProviderWithCustom = customDataProvider(dataProvider);
const history = createHistory();
//const dataProviderWithCustomResponse = customDataResponse(dataProvider);

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Admin history={history} loginPage={LoginPage} dashboard={Dashboard} dataProvider={dataProviderWithCustom} authProvider={authProvider}>
                <Resource name="acl-adv" options={{ label: 'Regras' }} list={AcladvList} edit={AcladvEdit} create={AcladvCreate} icon={ACLIcon} />
                <Resource name="vm" options={{ label: 'Virtual Machines' }} list={vmWareList} show={vmWareShow} edit={vmWareEdit} create={vmWareCreate} icon={VMIcon} />
            </Admin>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

---

## *Solved*

OK, I reinstalled react admin, history and oidc-client. Everything is working as expected now.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show us your `package.json`? Also, it would be awesome if you fork this sandbox in order to reproduce the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/5kmnz88jvx

Comment: looks like the language packages have changed from `aor-` to `ra-` so is it possible something in admin is still expecting `aor-language-english`? [relevant part of upgrade intructions](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#default-english-messages-moved-to-standalone-package)

Comment: @Kamschta, package.json: https://pastebin.com/KJfiF8vi. Ocaeon, I'm not upgrading from aor, I was always using ra. Thank you all. I'll check others informations passed.

Comment: Just a note. A simple code like the one from the demo is also rendering wrong. 

I'll try somethings later.

Simple Code from demo:
```import React from 'react';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');


const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <Resource name="users" list={ListGuesser} />
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Reminder you can answer your own question then mark the answer as the solution.